# Why my package is not downloable by pip?

Tags: python, pypi

I created the package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/avro3k/1.7.6-SNAPSHOT but when I do pip install avro3k in another machine I don't get the package installed, what is needed for this to function?

Comment: You registered it, but haven't uploaded anything. You need to `sdist` or `bdist` and `upload` your package.

Comment: http://guide.python-distribute.org/